# Geoserver and WMS endpoints

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wms

I'm trying to access a WMS endpoint through Openlayers to display the data in a slippy map.

Here's my code:

```
var basemap = new ol.source.TileWMS( " Layer Name 1", "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/oswgc-india/wms", {layers: 'oswgc-india:india_grouplayer'} );

         var map = new ol.Map({
                layers: [
                        basemap
                        ],
                target: 'map',
                view: new ol.View({
                        center: [312406.33, 6150500.21],
                        zoom: 5
                })
          });
```

In Geoserver, I have created a grouped layer called india_grouplayer in the workspace oswgc-india. However, my index.html with the embedded JavaScript just returns a blank page. I suspect that I'm missing configuration options in Geoserver, as I'm not exactly very familiar with the software.

Comment: look in the GeoServer log file to see what the issue is, also check the URL being requested in a browser and make sure it really is a blank image, then check the projections of your map and the request

Comment: @IanTurton Thank you for your comment. Browsing to the URL directly yields a "no applicable code" exception.

Comment: please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/326717/edit) to include the url being requested and the exact response you get back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is definitely wrong is that there is no layer definition and source is used as layer.

It should look something like this:

```
var mapSource = new ol.source.TileWMS( "Layer Name 1", "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/oswgc-india/wms", {layers: 'oswgc-india:india_grouplayer'} );

var mapLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: mapSource,
  extent: [ ... ]
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    mapLayer
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [312406.33, 6150500.21],
    zoom: 5
  })
});
```